# axWebBrowser no longer firing events / control error

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a project which contains the axWebBrowser control.  However, this project no longer fires ANY axwebbrowser1 events.  If I create a new project, the events fire just fine.  After deleting the axWebBrowser control, if I try to add the axWebBrowser control back to the form, I get this error:

[image: error being shown by pc]

What could be causing this error?  This error exists on both my desktop/laptop.  Do I need to just "suck it up" and recreate the UI from scratch?

Comment: What is axWebBrowser control?

Comment: it is the "Microsoft Web Browser" COM component. Long story short, and after a ton of testing, I just figured it out - deleting my solution's obj folder and then rebuilding solved my problem. Not sure what relation the Obj folder has to a control on a form though, I thought the Obj folder was more like an intermediary for the final binary

Comment: It's slightly odd to see a COM component in a .NET application these days. Isn't there a native .NET web browser component? In any case, you may expect all sorts of things with COM, so I'm glad you found the solution.

Comment: @Neolisk I knew this was coming :P.  I need to use MSHTML, with .getelementsbyname and I am dealing with a web page frame.  When I set .net WBC to .domdocument, .getelebyname method returns nothing, and no one could tell me how to set it to the specific frame on the webpage;  I asked that question here I think and it went unanswered.

Comment: Why not use [WebBrowser Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/aa752040(v=vs.85).aspx)? I understand it is probably the same thing, but nicely wrapped into native code, so hopefull you will have less trouble with it.

Comment: @Neolisk as stated above, I need to use MSHTML, with .getelementsbyname method and I am dealing with a web page frame. Setting htmldoc (as mshtml.htmldocument) = webbrowsercontrol1.document.domdocument returns nothing for .getelementsbyname method, and no one could explain why. I think it is because I am dealing with a frame src on the webpage, no one could tell me how to use mshtml with a frame in the WBC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting the /OBJ/ folder from my project and letting it rebuild, resolved the error.

Comment: This is a common problem. If something has weird behavior, this is one of the troubleshooting steps. Glad you found it.